# Apache 4.1 HttpClient POST and GET

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can anyone provide an example of how I could use `GET` and `POST` (Apache 4.1 HttpClient)?
Because most of the example that I found are using `3.x`

Comment: 4 years later, and it's still true. Not sure how making it many times more complex is an improvement.

Comment: Requests for examples are off-topic.  This Question should have been deleted a long time ago.